# What does 'spin the event loop' mean?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

I read a lot about how JavaScript is working. It collects events in a queue. A loop that checks for an event to take from the queue is called the Event Loop, but what does it mean if the Event Loop is spun? Is it the same as getting the next event from the queue?

Comment: @BrianTompsett OP didn't mention the DOM in their question

Answer (score 0):

"Spinning" means that loop performs its iterations.

Comment: Could you tell more? Maybe with an example?

Comment: It's hard to show an ecample, as this happens behind-the-scenes. Think of it as the machinery that makes your events, timeouts etc work.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to read some official guides about Event Loop:

- http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop
- https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick

And to check some talks about the Event Loop:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&ab_channel=JSConf
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNa9OMajw9w&ab_channel=node.js

Answering your question:
The event loop "spin" means that the Event loop performed run through all queues. After its run, the EL checks if there are active handles or some requests or timers which are still processing or haven't been done yet.

In other words, a "spin" means that the Event Loop have done a single iteration.